# Why does this function take an [[a]]?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, type-systems

I am writing Haskell code practicing tail recursion to inverse a list and have came up with this solution:

```
reverseh' [] list = list
reverseh' (x:xs) list = reverseh' (xs) (x ++ list)
reverse' x = reverseh' x []
```

It only works with list of list but I wanted it to be have type signature `[a] -> [a]`.

Could you please explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I have the same problem, your question helped me in finding a solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't get the expected type, it's a good idea to add an explicit type signature to tell the compiler what you want the type to be, here:

```
reverseh' :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Then you get a compilation error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[a]' with actual type `a'     
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by                     
      the type signature for reverseh' :: [a] -> [a] -> [a] 
      at reverseh.hs:1:14                                   
Relevant bindings include                                   
  list :: [a] (bound at reverseh.hs:3:18)                   
  xs :: [a] (bound at reverseh.hs:3:14)                     
  x :: a (bound at reverseh.hs:3:12)                        
  reverseh' :: [a] -> [a] -> [a] (bound at reverseh.hs:2:1) 
In the first argument of `(++)', namely `x'                 
In the second argument of reverseh', namely `(x ++ list)'
```

This tells you that in `(x ++ list)`, `x` needs to be of type `[a]` in order to typecheck, but with the type signature you have in mind, `x` really is of type `a`. So you want to replace `++` with a function of type `a -> [a] -> [a]`, and so you go with `(x : list)`.

Answer (score 3):

Because of `(x ++ list)` expression in the second line, typechecker thinks that `x :: [a]`. You wanted to write `(x : list)`, i guess.